# Elementals and Aliens

Tags: story, strategy, optimization, mazes

### Rules/Story

- You have been kidnapped and locked in the maze under the bathhouse you work at by 5 aliens: a **Mercurian**, **Venusian**, **Martian**, **Jovian**, and **Saturnian**.

  - Currently, the aliens are spread through the maze, doing various tasks, with no-one patrolling the maze. They aren't moving or paying much attention to their surroundings.
  - You can't pass any of the aliens' tiles without the right elemental.
  - When you pass an alien with the right elemental, it is removed from the game and is no longer there.
- You know the layout of the maze, and that there are 5 elemental creatures in it the **pyrausta**, **wobbling**, **creeper**, **automaton**, and **gnome**.

  - These are used as guards, and will follow and defend you once you have their attention.
  - Currently, they have been set to guard some of the important storage rooms. None of the elementals move, and they will always be on their start tiles.
  - You get each elemental by moving onto its tile.
- If your knowledge of alchemy is correct, then **each elemental will kill one of the aliens**:

  - The pyrausta kills the Mercurian.
  - The wobbling kills the Martian.
  - The creeper kills the Saturnian.
  - The automaton kills the Jovian.
  - The gnome kills the Venusian.
- One complicating factor is the **energy gates**.

  - When going through an energy gate, any elementals that you have are transformed and changed into another elemental. The transformation should go pyrausta > gnome > automaton > wobbling > creeper > pyrausta.
  - When you use an energy gate, it becomes a wall and cannot be reused or gone through again.
- While you have been bound and gagged, you can still crawl along and attract the attention of the elementals if you're near enough. **You can move one tile orthogonally**, or left/right/up/down, per move.

### Map

Here is a map of the maze. The capital letters are the elementals, the lowercase letters are the aliens (Martian is t), @ is your starting position, % is the gates, = is the exit, and # is the paths that you may walk through.

```
       C            
       ####j#=      
       m v          
     A############          
       %         #   
       ###  W    t  
       G s####%### 
            #   P   
            @
```

### Puzzle

What is the fewest number of moves (going orthogonally from tile to tile) to get out of the maze? **The goal is to reach the exit, without going through an alien without the right elemental or going through an energy gate twice.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128226/discussion-between-ichthys-king-and-chris-cudmore).

Comment: [Penpa Link](https://bit.ly/3fyN0zb) Note that for simplicity, I have **renamed the elementals to be the capital initial letters of their corresponding monsters** for clarity. All the other notations are left unchanged (unless I made a mistake)

Comment: What is your definition of using an energy gate? Transforming an elemental or just passing through it? If I pass through an energy gate empty handed, does it still disactivate and get sealed off?

Comment: @Ankit Moving through a gate activates it, regardless of the elementals in your possession. Any such are transformed, according to the rule.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative map:

```
  5
  ####C#X
  A B
3############
  G         #
  ###  4    D
  2 E####G###
       #   1
       S
```

Here, the elementals are numbered 1-5 in transformation order, and are paired to the aliens they slay in the usual way (A1, B2, C3, D4, E5); S, X, and G denote the start, the end, and the gates.
The starting point is now obvious:

> The starting point is boxed in by D and E, and you can only grab elementals 4 and 1 before exiting the section between them. You can't slay D, because he's on the other side of the gate - 4 would become 5. So the only option is to grab 4, enter the gate, **then turn around and slay E.**

> You are now carrying elemental 5, and are forced to pass through the next gate, which will turn it into 1 and let you kill A.* However, you must also kill C, and you have two options:
>  - Grab 2, and transform it in the second gate.
>  - Grab 3.
>  The former is a one-cell detour and the latter is two, so the first choice is the better one. All told, S-4-G-E-2-G-A-C-X takes 3+3+5+4+2+2+5+2 = **26 moves.**

> *[Edited to flesh out this reasoning more convincingly] After the forced moves leading to the second gate, the situation is as follows: Both gates are locked, you're carrying a used 1, and possibly a 3, and the level contains an available 3, a 5 behind A or B, and a 1 behind D (which you couldn't grab earlier due to backing out of the first gate). Since no more transformations are possible, the 1 behind D is unobtainable - since no 2's can be obtained, the only way forward must be the used 1.

Comment: I didn't realize that elementals are reusable. If so then well done!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is currently incorrect due to me misreading the problem. I will update it asap.

### The answer is

> 30 moves

### The path

Step 1:

> go to wobbling (1-3)

Step 2:

> go to nearest energy gate and convert the wobbling to a creeper (4-6)

Step 3:

> going back the way you came from, go to Saturnian and kill it with your creeper (7-11)

Step 4:

> go to the gnome (12-15)

Step 5:

> go to the nearest energy gate and convert the gnome to a pyrusta (16-17)

Step 6:

> go to the automaton (18-20)

Step 7:

> go to the mercurian and kill it with your pyrusta (21-23)

Step 8:

> go to the jovian and kill it with your automaton (24-28)

Step 9:

> go to exit (29-30)

Comment: The gnome turns into an automaton, not a pyrausta